# Contour Plots in pgfplots not running in TeXStudio

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texstudio, gnuplot

I would like to create contour plots. I have updated MikTek 2.9 the following are my current updates that I think are relevant.

pgfplots: 1.17

TeXStudio: 3.1.1

Windows 10

When searching StackExchange a lot of solutions to these problem involve -Shell Escape, however my command line in TexStudio has the following:

> pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex

However, this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
            title={$x^2-x\,y$},
            enlarge x limits,
            view={0}{90},
            xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
            small,
            ]
            \addplot3[domain=-3:3,
            domain y=-3:3,
            contour gnuplot={levels={-1,1},labels=false},
            thick,samples=50,samples y=50,
            ] {x^2-x*y};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this code still does not run properly and won't even generate an image. I get the following error from the log file:

> Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
> s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}).

> \openout3 = `"Contour Plot Test_contourtmp0.dat"'.

> \openout3 = `"Contour Plot Test_contourtmp0.script"'.

> runsystem(gnuplot ""Contour Plot Test"_contourtmp0.script")...executed.

> ! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{"Contour Plot Test"_contourtmp0.tabl
> e} could not be opened.

> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H   for immediate help.
> ...

> l.16           ] {x^2-x*y};

> This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help.
> Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by order and method.

> Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away) on input line 16.

> [warning /pgfplots/warning/plot without coordinates]

> Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction z). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 17.

With the update to pgfplots 1.17 it didn't seem like I needed to install gnuplot as a separate install like a lot of older posts on StackExchange suggest.

This is my first time writing a question on StackExchange and I've been scouring the site for a couple days looking for an answer to this and I hope I am not repeating questions and I hope someone may be able to help with the solution. I am not a TeX super use by any stretch of the imagination, but I have been using it for a few years, but I am not the type of user that gets into the nitty gritty of file paths, so I don't know why gnuplot will not load with the most recent update.

Thank you to any help you can give me, I hope I have provided enough information to chase down the problem.

Comment: Welcome. Have you installed an uptodate version of gnuplot? Have you used `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18` in you texstudio command for pgflatex?

Comment: `enable-write18` didn't work when I added it.

This was kind of part of my question. When I read the release notes and stuff on pgfplots 1.17 it referenced gnuplot as being part of the code. Is this not true for their build from 1.16? I was under the impression I didn't have to install gnuplot as a separate system.

Comment: You have to install gnuplot at your PATH for latex in order to use it. Have a look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aLq2.png

Comment: Okay, so I've installed gnuplot separately and it still won't work. I've told the install to update my Path, but I can't find the screenshot your shared above at all.

Comment: Can you run gnuplot and which version did you installed? You can type `gnuplot -v` in your cmd ...

Comment: The version I downloaded was 5.4.1. So, I've opened gnuplot it says 

`gnuplot -v` 

is an invalid command though, but the file I downloaded is 5.4.1. I don't know anything about gnuplot or it's code, so I just know how to open it.

Comment: Ok. When you type only `gnuplot` you see something? You can also try `path` and check, if gnuplot is on this list

Comment: Where exactly am I typing this stuff? In the gnuplot window or texstudio?

Comment: Sorry, you can go to the windows window and type `cmd` or at texstudio `tools -> open terminal`

Comment: ah yes, that worked. `path` gives me a path for everything and `gnuplot` give me the info of version 5.4 patchlevel 1

Comment: I guess I should add, the path for gnuplot it gave was `C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin`. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Is this path in your `PATH` directory?

Comment: Okay, this is where I don't know the directory stuff very well. How do I find the path in TexStudio? Or is this something to do with MikTek??

Comment: Were you able to open your comand terminal? `Press Windows+R to open “Run” box. Type “cmd” and then click “OK” to open a regular Command Prompt.`

Comment: Yes, I've got the command prompt open :)

Comment: ok. and now type `path`and check, if gnuplot is in this list

Comment: yes, it's in this list as well, same path as above.

Comment: Is it still not working? Maybe you have to reinstall gnuplot from here (https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.4.1/), since you did not saw the pannel of the screenshot ...

Comment: Nah, it still doesn't work. I tried reinstalling and that panel you linked above still didn't show up. So, I just don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: Actually, just saw your link. that actually where I downloaded it from.

Comment: Can you open gnuplot? What happens if you type `gnuplot` in the cmd?

Comment: yeah gnuplot opens up just fine when I type that into cmd. It just refuses to talk to TexStudio for whatever reason.

Comment: What is the name of your .tex file?

Comment: Sorry, I had to teach a class. Anyway, Contour Plot Test.tex is my file name. In trying to run the file it does create a Contour Plot Test_contourtmp0.dat and Contour Plot Test_contourtmp0.script

Comment: Can you remove the space in the file name and try again?

Comment: Well... I'll be damned. That worked...

Comment: I had the same problem, so my struggles were useful after all

Comment: Yes definitely worth it! Thank you so much! I'm not used to code nowadays hating spaces...